# How to find patterns in image in js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, ocr, object-detection, yolo

I am new to AI and text recognition from an image world, I am trying to recognition characters patterns from an image using javascript, but I have absolutely no idea where to even start. My goal is to recognize characters of this format: 000-00-000 or 00-000-00. inside of images (license plates). Can someone please refrence me to resources where I can find this information or tell me about certine libraries that does that?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a way to iterate through the pixels. I used to put it on a canvas and then use:

```
const imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
const data = imgData.data;
```

having to do all this for each image did take a while. I would find a different strategy to iterate through the pixels but this works.

A license plate is double as wide as it's high. have a loop iterate through the picture to find rectangles that contain mostly a dark colour and a light colour. Then find patterns in them by finding places where there are sudden changes in colour so it can train itself.

Make sure you have somewhere to store the data the computer is learning a .pkl file is good from what I hear but as a student, I used txt files (not the best, trust me).

I would first make sure that the algorithm can recognize license plates and make a function that colours it a solid colour or print its coordinates to make sure it works, then start giving it images and the text on the license plate. Have it log patterns in its learning files for each letter so it can learn to read.

Make sure your images are good quality and good luck ;)